# JAXB With Axis2 Putting Object ID while Serializing

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization

I am stuck with very strange problem with following tech-stack:

Weblogic 12c
JDK 1.7
Axis2 1.5.2 with integrated JAXB

Activity: Upgrading project from Weblogic 10.3.6 to 12.1.1 including JDK upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7

Problem Description: While creating OM Element, JAXB is putting object ID of child object instead of value of parameter under child object. The issue is seen in JDK 1.7 only where as it's working perfect in JDK 1.6

Request.java

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02}NumberOfNotes"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02}NoteData"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "NumberOfNotes",
    "NoteData"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
public class Request {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger")
    protected BigInteger NumberOfNotes;
    @XmlElement(name = "NoteData", required = true)
    protected NoteData NoteData;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the NumberOfNotes property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigInteger }
     *     
     */
    public BigInteger getNumberOfNotes() {
        return NumberOfNotes;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the NumberOfNotes property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigInteger }
     *     
     */
    public void setNumberOfNotes(BigInteger value) {
        this.NumberOfNotes = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the NoteData property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link NoteData }
     *     
     */
    public NoteData getNoteData() {
        return NoteData;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the NoteData property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link NoteData }
     *     
     */
    public void setNoteData(NoteData value) {
        this.NoteData = value;
    }

}
```

NoteData.java

```
package com.org.w3.spec.prd.services._2011._02;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="NoteDataDetails" maxOccurs="50" minOccurs="0">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element ref="{http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02}numberOfNoteLines"/>
 *                   &lt;sequence>
 *                     &lt;element ref="{http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02}NoteLineText" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;/sequence>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "NoteDataDetails"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "NoteData")
public class NoteData {

    protected List<NoteData.NoteDataDetails> NoteDataDetails;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the NoteDataDetails property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the NoteDataDetails property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getNoteDataDetails().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link NoteData.NoteDataDetails }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<NoteData.NoteDataDetails> getNoteDataDetails() {
        if (NoteDataDetails == null) {
            NoteDataDetails = new ArrayList<NoteData.NoteDataDetails>();
        }
        return this.NoteDataDetails;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element ref="{http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02}numberOfNoteLines"/>
     *         &lt;sequence>
     *           &lt;element ref="{http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02}NoteLineText" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;/sequence>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "numberOfNoteLines",
        "NoteLineText"
    })
    public static class NoteDataDetails {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected BigInteger numberOfNoteLines;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected List<NoteLineText> NoteLineText;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the numberOfNoteLines property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link BigInteger }
         *     
         */
        public BigInteger getNumberOfNoteLines() {
            return numberOfNoteLines;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the numberOfNoteLines property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link BigInteger }
         *     
         */
        public void setNumberOfNoteLines(BigInteger value) {
            this.numberOfNoteLines = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the NoteLineText property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the NoteLineText property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getNoteLineText().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link NoteLineText }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<NoteLineText> getNoteLineText() {
            if (NoteLineText == null) {
                NoteLineText = new ArrayList<NoteLineText>();
            }
            return this.NoteLineText;
        }

    }

}
```

NoteLoneText.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="Line">
 *           &lt;simpleType>
 *             &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string">
 *               &lt;maxLength value="50"/>
 *               &lt;whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
 *             &lt;/restriction>
 *           &lt;/simpleType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "line"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "NoteLineText")
public class NoteLineText {

    @XmlElement(name = "Line", required = true)
    protected String line;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the line property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the line property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setLine(String value) {
        this.line = value;
    }

}
```

SendNoteStub.java

```
private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(com.org.w3.spec.prd.services._2011._02.prdAddNoteRes param, boolean optimizeContent)
                throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
                    try {
                        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext context = wsContext;
                        javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                        marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

                        org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory factory = org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();

                        JaxbRIDataSource source = new JaxbRIDataSource( com.org.w3.spec.prd.services._2011._02.prdAddNoteRes.class,
                                                                        param,
                                                                        marshaller,
                                                                        "http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02",
                                                                        "AddNoteRes");
                        org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace namespace = factory.createOMNamespace("http://w3.org.com/spec/prd/services/2011/02",
                                                                           null);
                        return factory.createOMElement(source, "prdAddNoteRes", namespace);
                    } catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException bex){
                        throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(bex);
                    }
                }
```

Generated XML:

```
<PrdAddLoanNoteReq xmlns="http://w3.org.com/spec/Prd/services/2011/02"><transactionId>BZNSQT</transactionId><numberOfLoanNotes>1</numberOfLoanNotes><LoanNoteData><loanNoteDataDetails><numberOfLoanNoteLines>3</numberOfLoanNoteLines><loanNoteLineText>com.org.w3.spec.Prd.services._2011._02.LoanNoteLineText@1182716</loanNoteLineText><loanNoteLineText>com.org.w3.spec.Prd.services._2011._02.LoanNoteLineText@58ae15e9</loanNoteLineText><loanNoteLineText>com.org.w3.spec.Prd.services._2011._02.LoanNoteLineText@d20a17b</loanNoteLineText></loanNoteDataDetails></LoanNoteData></PrdAddLoanNoteReq>
```

Issue in generated XML is that under LoanNoteLineText tag, JAXB is putting Object ID instead of value of parameter Line.

Any help in this regards in highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was occurring due to incorrect JAXB implementation getting loaded. Updating Weblogic Start-up Arguments resolved the issue.